# How can I view Markdown text inside Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, markdown

What can I do with markup files (.mkd) inside Visual Studio? I am looking for a way to display the Markdown comments / instructions in some collective manner.

Comment: Remember that markdown files are just ordinary text files.

Comment: It is now [built into Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown) (no extensions needed) - an opportunity for a new answer (rep$$...). An answer should address the possibly non-standard file extension *.mkd (the standard is *.md). Or perhaps the accepted answer is somewhat misleading?

Comment: For an all in one solution try Markdown All In One
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one

Comment: This question is unfortunately closed to accept new answers; Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5 released on Feb 21, 2023 introduced native markdown support ([release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes)). After opening a `.md` file you can **Show Markdown Preview** using **Shift+F7** (or by clicking "Preview" above the content). If you just created a new markdown file you might have to save, close and re-open it for VS to register it as a markdown file and give you this option. Happy documenting!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Maybe you can use the extension **Markdown Mode**

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0855e23e-4c4c-4c82-8b39-24ab5c5a7f79

Comment: View > Other windows > Markdown Preview Window.

Comment: Instant markdown works well https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-instant-markdown

Comment: But instant markdown it is only for visual studio code no?

Comment: `Markdown Mode` sure does render out to some richtext. They could really use a stylesheet. Cool plugin otherwise, the code editor syntax highlighting is enough for me. @RubendelaFuente I think you are correct about `Instant Markdown` and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The above markdown is already outdated for the latest VS.

Answer (score 133):

The accepted answer is five years old, and the respective extension supports only up to Visual Studio 2015. Today, for *Visual Studio 2019* and below, I would recommend [Markdown Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor) by Mads Kristensen. It has over 400K installs, supports GitHub and other flavors, live preview window, automatic HTML file generation, and much more. Works with both file extensions `.md` and `.mkd.`.

You can also use *Visual Studio Code* instead of Visual Studio, then you have excellent markdown support with live preview built-in. There is an extension [Markdown Preview Github Styling](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles). For even more functionality, another great extension is [Markdown All In One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one).

### EDIT 2023-04-04

As noted by @gridtrack and @Erik Bongers in the comments, Visual Studio 17.5 and greater now has markdown preview built-in (together with Syntax highlighting, which already existed before).

Comment: For people who only want to view the preview, VSCode provides this out of the box. Try typing `Markdown` in the *Command Palette* https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/languages/markdown/

Comment: VS 2019 has great MarkDown syntax highlighting with color.  However, Markdown Editor does not provide color syntax highlighting. Enabling MarkDown Editor disables the VS color syntax highlighting, but nicely includes a wysiwyg viewer.

Comment: VS2022 requires this version of the Markdown Editor: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor2

Comment: How to install it?

Comment: @Black: Install it in Visual Studio 2022 via menu Extensions -> select Online -> enter "markdown" -> select the one you want -> click Download .

Comment: As of VS 17.5, there's a PREVIEW button at the top left of the md file window. No extension needed anymore.

Answer (score 9):

[Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) is a great plug-in if you want to see Markdown files inside of Visual Studio. It has an editor with live preview for Markdown.

Also it includes several other features for web development (most of them are integrated directly into Visual Studio with the next release).

Comment: FYI, Markdown Editor has been yanked from Web Essentials into a different extension than the one the @Ruben listed. It can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor

Comment: @DanCsharpster Markdown editor is in Web Essentials 2017. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017

Comment: Did anyone get Markdown Editor (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor) to work in Visual Studio 2019? I cant get the .md content rendered.

Comment: @thomasgalliker Markdown Editor works fine in VS2019. Just restart VS after downloading ME extension

Answer (score 4):

With VScode one can open a preview tab with:

Open Preview (Ctrl+Shift+V) or Open Preview to the Side command (Ctrl+K V).

Comment: Does not work in Visual Studio 2019. Maybe this only works for unspecified extensions. I downvoted this answer because it screws up Visual Studio's Solution Explorer docking

Comment: I think this is for VS Code, not for VS.

Comment: I put my up vote back, I should have read "VScode" in your answer.  (Ctrl+Shift+V) works as you described in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Down vote, as this causes more harm than good. The question is about VS, not VSC,

Comment: Answer should be about VS not VSC.